How to login or bypass mixpanel application?
I'm trying to create a Cypress script to perform a login to Mixpanel, make some modifications to my dashboard, and schedule it to run every day using Windows Task Scheduler. I've already written the script and handled the scheduling part. However, I'm stuck at the login step. Does anyone know how to log in to the Mixpanel application using Cypress?
Expected result: login to Mixpanel successfully using a Cypress script.

The first thing to note is that Cypress is not a general web automation framework like WebDriver, it is a testing framework. As such, you would be better off with another tool for this aim.
Secondly, the Mixpanel site will sometimes throw up a captcha which will (sometimes) prevent any automation attempt.
But if you want to see some code that can perform the login, the following would work (sometimes). Note there are some advanced concepts used.
cy.visit('https://mixpanel.com/login/')             // go straight to login page

cy.get('[name="emailInput"]').type('eleanor@mixpanel.com')
cy.get('[name="emailInput"]').blur()            // blur this control to validate it

cy.get('mp-gdpr-banner')              // remove cookies banner (it hides some fields)
  .shadow()                        // there is a shadow DOM here 
  .contains('button', 'Decline')  // choose to accept or decline (your choice)
  .click()

cy.contains('button', 'Log in with SSO').click()  // go to SSO screen
                                                 // here you sometimes get captcha
                                               // which you cannot automate passed

// next screen is another domain, so wrap in an origin command
cy.origin('https://mixpanel.okta.com', () => {
  cy.get('input[autocomplete="username"]').type('eleanor')
  cy.get('input[autocomplete="current-password"]').type('pword')
  cy.get('input[value="Sign in"]').click()
})

That is the so-called "manual" login, it uses fields. If you want to explore using SSO "API" process, look at Auth0 Authentication.
The process is too long and varied to describe here, but Cypress provides a sample application you can adapt.
